# MVC Custom ControllerFactory and ActionInvoker lifestyle

Tags: model-view-controller, castle-windsor, castle

I've read many topics, but still can't find an answer: which lifestyle is preferred for custom ControllerFactory and ActionInvoker for registration in DI container? Can somebody explain a difference between Transient and PerWebRequest (I use Castle Windsor in my project) in the scope of MVC application? I tried both and both work well on my local machine. But what is better and WHY?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Trasient lifestyle, you need to release your objects after you use it otherwise Garbage Collector will not be able to reclaim them. But there is no need to release objects for PerWebRequest lifestyle.

Reference:
https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/lifestyles.md#transient